# Debian Linux / strange default partition sizes

Tags: linux, partitioning

Installing Debian on a 512 GB SSD, I get the following default partitions:

```
/      10 GB
/home 486 GB
/swap  14 GB
```

Considering I have 64 GB RAM, aren't these values quite strange?

Shouldn't the swap space be twice as the available RAM?

Isn't the / partition way too small?

Comment: The "2x" rule for swap is antiquated; if you're using hibernation, should be 1:1, otherwise should be less.  With 64GB of RAM you might not need any at all.  As far as the root partition size... that seems weird with no additional partition for /usr (and perhaps /var)

Comment: Depending on usage (e.g. this is a single-user system), multiple partitions is just more of a headache than anything on a single disk.

Answer (score 3):

**There's nothing wrong with your swap partition's size.**

Allocating twice as much swap space as the amount of RAM you have is a *cargo cult*. It made sense at some point, but modern systems have much more RAM than ones in use when this rule of thumb was coined. At this point usually it doesn't make sense. [Ubuntu Community FAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) has slightly more modern tips:

> **How much swap do I need?**
>
> For less then 1GB of physical memory (RAM), it's highly recommended that the swap space should, as a base minimum, be equal to the amount of RAM. Also, it's recommended that the swap space is maximum twice the amount of RAM depending upon the amount of hard disk space available for the system because of diminishing returns.
>
> For more modern systems (>1GB), your swap space should be at a minimum be equal to your physical memory (RAM) size "if you use hibernation", otherwise you need a minimum of round(sqrt(RAM)) and a maximum of twice the amount of RAM. The only downside to having more swap space than you will actually use, is the disk space you will be reserving for it.

However, this guide still doesn't take into account such large RAM amounts as yours - 64 GB is still *a lot* compared to most systems in use today. I suppose you may want to use it for some memory-expensive jobs, like data crunching or as a server. In that case you shouldn't rely on rules of thumb, but actually consider what kind of system load you should expect and adjust swap size.

If it's just a regular, slightly more powerful system, then you should also consider your use cases and adjust. If you want to use hibernation, you'll need at least as much swap as the amount of RAM you have. (Linux dumps memory to swap space when hibernating.) Otherwise, you should probably be fine with what Debian proposed or even less.

**The `/` partition may be too small**, but it depends on your usage habits. It would probably be just fine for a HTPC used mostly for watching movies (they take way more space than OS, player, browser and maybe few other essential programs combined). If you're going to use this PC for multiple tasks, you may run out of space at some point.

If you're not sure how much space you'll need on storage partitions, you should consider setting up LVM. It will let you allocate more chunks to partitions as you run out of disk space.